# How to install BLEServer.h and AVRdude.h

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-low-energy

Chatgpt suggested the following code to upload for my Blend Micro to advertise it as a peripheral. However, I do not have the BLEServer.h and AVRdude.h packages installed. Could anyone help me install these packages? Or, another way to advertise my Blend Micro as a BLE peripheral would be helpful too.

Also, I understand the `SERVICE_UUID` (which is `"713D0000-503E-4C75-BA94-3148F18D941E"` for my Blend Micro; please correct me if I'm wrong), but do not know the `CHARACTERISTIC_UUID`. Could anyone help me with that too?

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <AVRdude.h>

// Replace with the UUIDs for your BLE service and characteristic
#define SERVICE_UUID        "your-service-uuid-here"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "your-characteristic-uuid-here"

void setup() {
  // Initialize the BLE device
  BLEDevice::init("Your BLE Device Name");

  // Create the BLE server and service
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
    CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
  );
  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World!");
  pService->start();

  // Start advertising
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void loop() {
  // Check if there is data available on the serial port
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // Read the incoming data as a string
    String data = Serial.readString();

    // Print the data to the serial monitor
    Serial.println("Received data: " + data);
  }
}
```

Thank you,
TS

Comment: Short of searching for the file names on your favourite search engine. It's purely a guess where the AI scraped that code from. You're better off finding a library for your microcontroller that is properly documented.

Comment: "chatgpt suggested" = "if it compiles at all, it probably has a lot of bugs and poor practices".

Comment: We might need to create a new rule - ‘no questions related to the output of chat-gpt ‘. Just posting defective code probably re-enforces the learning of it. The first task I gave chat-gpt resulted in code that did not compile and had critical flaws.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with @Kartman that questions about ChatGPT responses should be rejected to minimize information pollution.

Comment: If the original poster just searches for "Blend Micro" the second entry is the GitHub location of documentation and examples for this board.  It's all there. Google is your friend, and ChatGPT is a poser.

Comment: We should delete any reference to ‘lechat’ as any mention may have a reinforcing (negative) effect. The old Maxim: ‘garbage in, garbage out’ applies. What happens when you feed the AI with the rubbish it has created?  <end rant> yes, I’ve strayed way off topic.

Comment: @Kartman see https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9793/should-questions-about-chatgpt-responses-be-closed

Answer (score 1):

ChatGPT is a bullshit generator. It generates streams of plausible-sounding bullshit which for some reason many people actually believe. As you can see, it has generated something that looks like useful code, which is actually totally useless. The BLEServer library is for ESP32 and avrdude is something that runs on your computer to upload the program to the Arduino.

The solution is to not use GPT to write your code.